# Xampp redirects to dashboard

Tags: macos, xampp

i recently installed Xampp (5.6.24) on my mac which is running osx Yosemite.
Hi changed the document root directory in the http.conf file ( which route is /Xampp/etc/http.conf) and changed the name to Xampp htdocs folder, but my new htdocs folder always redirect to the dashboard page.
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you may have index.php file in htdocs folder thats why it redirect to dashboard.

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
    exit;
?>
Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
```

in this header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/'); redirects you to dashboard.

Comment: Yeah i tried to comment it but it does not work. Changed the folder name or the file name too, but it always redirect to the dashboard